# Riley Riddle 10: Feeling Raw

Tags: riddle

I start with a defunct ISO-used code.
I end in two hours, so the Chinese had bode.
In the centre, a typical librarian's tool.
My answer is that of my last middle's dual.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you

> SUSHI?

I start with a defunct ISO-used code.

> [SU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-3), the 2-letter ISO code for the Soviet Union.

I end in two hours, so the Chinese had bode.

> [SHI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Traditional_Chinese_timekeeping#Dual_hour:_Sh%C3%AD), a dual-hour measure in traditional Chinese timekeeping.

In the centre, a typical librarian's tool.

> SH, telling patrons to be quiet in the library.

My answer is that of my last middle's dual.

> A reference to @flashstorm's Riley Riddle #9, whose infix (middle) was OMI; the word OMI is now popularly used in restaurant names such as OMI SUSHI.

From @flashstorm, the title reference is that

> sushi is usually served raw.

Thanks, @flashstorm for the update!

Comment: @flashstorm Great riddle! But make sure, however, that any comments that might reveal the answer be written in [Rot13](https://www.rot13.com/) (like how answers must be written in spoiler tags/quotes). For example: (ROT13) Nsgre ernqvat lbhe pbzzrag, V gubhtug gung gur jbeq FHFUV vf gur nafjre. (V nyfb fghql Wncnarfr, naljnl.) Naq nsgre ybbxvat ng gur nafjre nobir, vg frrzf yvxr V jnf evtug.